# Set width of card with Rows inside to dynamically adapt to the width of text length in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i make a cards width in flutter to adapt to the length of its child text-length?

I have a card which content fetches from firebase like this, where every line in the Column has a Row with one Icon- and one Text-widget:

```
Card(child: Column(children: [Row(children: [Icons(Icons.icon1), Text(FIREBASEDATA)]), Row(children: [Icons(Icons.icon1), Text(FIREBASEDATA)]),Row(children: [Icons(Icons.icon1), Text(FIREBASEDATA)]),]),)
```

I want the width of the card be so it just covers the text just in the same way that the cards heigth just covers the content.
I think that the rows inside the Column gets infinite width and thats why the Card doesnt adapt to the size of the text content.

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of your current card?

Comment: I updated the question not with a screenshot but the code now is exactly what I got. I missed to write out about the Rows before wich probably is the root of my problem since I think the Rows gets infinite width

Comment: the image is still not attached and if you give row this property mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min it will not take the full width but will take the width it needed

Comment: Yes I wrote that I didnt attach an image. Thanks for the help you solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 Card(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [Icons(Icons.icon1), Text(FIREBASEDATA)],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [Icons(Icons.icon1), Text(FIREBASEDATA)],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [Icons(Icons.icon1), Text(FIREBASEDATA)],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Setting MainAxisSize.min for the mainAxisSize property means that the widget will take up only the minimum amount of space along its main axis that is required to accommodate its contents. This is in contrast to MainAxisSize.max, which means that the widget will take up as much space along its main axis as possible.

So, the purpose of setting MainAxisSize.min is to make a Row or Column take up the least amount of space necessary to display its children. This can be useful in situations where you want to conserve space or if you want to align multiple rows or columns closely together.

Comment: Great answer, I tried this and it works! But I also wonder if one thing more is possible to solve with this solution: Now the elements in each row aligns to the center but I want all Icons to start over eachother to the left of the Card. This probalby could be solved wih Align or something similiar but I cant figure out where to place it.

Comment: I figured out how to do it, just set the Colums crossAxisAlignment to CrossAxisAlignment.start.